# Were semi-marine animals on Noah's Ark?

Tags: animals, fish, mabul, noach-noah-the-man

Otters, alligators, salamanders, frogs, penguins, seals, polar bears, sea lions, platypuses, beavers, sea snakes, sea turtles, etc. These animals to varying degrees need to be able to be both on land and in the ocean to survive for an indefinite period of time. Were they on the Ark, and if so, were they on it continuously during the entire flood? Do any commentaries address this question?